# I change my font and got error when blod text in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, fonts

i just change my font website to Questrial (Google font). And my language is Vietnamese, when i bold text it show smaller than normarl text.

Please help me fix that, thank a lot

Ex link : https://digitalbyrick.com/hieu-ve-edgerank-de-tang-toi-da-do-hien-thi-cua-fanpage/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHWO1.jpg)

Comment: The font you are using doesn't have a bold version, you'll need to load the bold version first if it exist, or use a different font.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere else in your CSS, you have:

```css
b, strong { color: black; font-size: 18px; }
```

That’s being inherited by all those words in `<strong>` tags, while the paragraph font size is `21px`.

It doesn’t appear related to the font, as that still happens if you change the font:

[image: Screenshot of website with font using browser default]

As Ali_k pointed out in the comment, Questrial doesn’t appear to have a bold style designed however, so if you try and change the font-weight, you may end up with faux bolding (depending on your other CSS).

Comment: Thank you a lot, i fixed my site. I fogot i was custom my CSS in past. b, strong { color: black; font-size: 21px; }, i fixed like that

Comment: You’re welcome! If you could mark this answer as Accepted, that would be great.